# Why does renaming a section within index.html and style.css cause the section to disappear?

Tags: html, css

Note in both sets of code, there is a section named "robot" I want to add a different on-screen section for the robot's status that I want to name "robot_status" and rename this section to "robot_motion", so - as a test - I renamed the section in both index.html and style.css, saved everything, and then:

- The server and nginx proxy, (for SSL), is fully shut down on the robot.
- The browser is closed and re-opened.
- After navigating to the URL for the display, I hit F-12 and then right-click "refresh" and then "empty cache and hard restart"
- I then restart all the server-side processes and refresh the browser again.

Results:

- The on-screen panel that shows the robot's motion status is missing.
- No errors or warnings are thrown in the browser's console window.

I don't know what the problem is, or even how to find it as there are no errors to indicate what I am doing wrong.

```css
#zone_joystick {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#video_source {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("/static/plane_loading.gif"), url('/static/waiting.svg');
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.robot {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 220px;
  left: 0.5%;
  top: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(223, 226, 219, 0.7);
}

.overlay {
  /* element always visible and covering the entire viewport */
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  /* include the image as background */
  background-image: url("Graticule_Images/Graticule-transparent-dark-violet.png");
  /* letting the image cover the entire viewport */
  background-size: cover;
  /* cenetring the image vertically and horizontally */
  background-position: center;
  /* positive z-index ensures that the overlay is always top z-axis wise */
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css" />
  <script src="static/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/throttle.js"></script>
  <script src="static/Joystick_Data_Test.js"></script>

  <title>GoPiGo3 Joystick Data Test</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="zone_joystick">
      <script language="JavaScript">
        document.write('<img id="video_source" src="' + window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':5001' + '/stream.mjpg' + '"/>');
      </script>
    </div>

    <div class="robot">
      Joystick Data Test
      <ul>
        <li id="motion_state">Motion State: Waiting for Joystick</li>
        <li id="angle_dir">Direction: None</li>
        <li id="time_stamp">Timestamp: 0</li>
        <li id="force">Applied Force: 0.00</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the code files are in the section `robot`?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. Additionally, to add a picture showing the pane missing, I renamed the sections again, restarted everything, (as I always do to make sure cache is flushed), and this time the pane appeared with the renamed sections.  Confusion reigns supreme. I wish I knew how to ask the browser why it isn't showing what I want it to show.

Comment: I don't see `robot_motion` or `robot_status` in the code you've shared. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JimJRHarris I think you mean that the code files are both in a folder called `robot`

Comment: Quentin: Please read the original question as this is fully explained there and yes, I have already read the sections you suggested. I am really trying not to post a 200 meg question - if you want to see the entire codebase, the repository is here: https://github.com/jharris1993/New_Remote_Camera_Robot/tree/Video-Enhancements. @Ethan No.  the "code" is exactly what you see.  What I posted was the "working" version.  The version that did NOT work is identical except that "robot" was changed to "robot_motion" as I mentioned above.